# How far should I go to handle network problems in code?

Tags: c#, sql, network-programming, recovery

I have clients with really bad networks, including bad mappings at the gateways and issues with aliasing. Sometimes they go days without a hitch, other days our services fail because they can't connect to the database or the connections get mysteriously dropped.

How far should a program (namely a service) go to recover or retry? Is it reasonable to have their network folks get it working properly or should I take upon myself to survive its flakiness?

Comment: If you want additional input, I'll recommend taking a look at the book Release It! by Michael Nygaard as it contains a lot of good advice on how to build systems for less than optimal conditions (i.e. the real world).

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - I have this book, it is excellent. I am trying to get a feel from the fellow stack overflowers about it; I slant towards simply failing and having checkpoints for recovery if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, it's reasonable to expect their network to work ... you wouldn't tell someone that the car they bought is broken because they don't have and roads to drive it on, would you?

2) That said: program defensively.  When you build a car, you can't expect everything to be a perfectly smooth interstate highway.

More specifically, I like to build retry mechanisms into my systems: I'll wrap something in 'retryable' logic, which lets you specify the number of retries. Typically, the retry period will have quadratic backoff: say, it tries after n*n seconds, for 1..n where n is the number of retries, or use fib(n) so you have something like 1,1,2,3,5 second retries.  The backoff helps prevent causing unnecessary strain on the upstream resource

If, after a set number of retries, you can either throw an exception (which can be caught and inform a user or other modules of the error), or logged, depending on the severity.

Comment: Fibonacci also has exponential growth.

Comment: That sequence and the fibonacci sequence grow quadratically, not exponentially.

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't that run against fault tolerance, though - more specifically the "fail fast" concept?

Comment: Not necessarily -- an individual module might 'fail fast' (say, an attempt to retrieve a network resource) rather than waiting for the resource to become availible. The rest of the system is notified of that failure, and some fault-handling system decides what to do (retry, throw exception).

Comment: @ThomSmith, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_numbers#Closed-form_expression the formula is exponential in `n`.